# Password not recognized after Apple servicing

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password, data-transfer, data-recovery

After coming back from the Apple center my Mac does not recognize the password.
When I try to change it through AppleID, my Mac does not manage to connect to iCloud’s server.

Tried to reset it through <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `resetpassword` on the terminal. But I get the same mistake. The same goes if I try to update OS (currently on Sierra BTW). Tried to reset all internet connections <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+Pwr, but did not have any luck.

After 1.30h in call with Apple Support, they told me I should completely reset my machine but I would like to not lose my data.

Do you maybe have any other solution to recover the password or save my data?

Apple MacBook Pro 13" 2016

Comment: How many accounts are there on the login screen, or is there a "switch accounts" option under your password prompt? I would think if you brought it into an Apple Store, the tech who worked on your machine would be on the receipt. You should ask them specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Take your MacBook Pro back to where it was worked on. Your machine should have been returned to you in usable condition.

This is, unfortunately, a lesson all should learn: back up *all* your data *before* having any work done.